# Windows has killed my Ubuntu partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning

I have two physical HDD on my laptop. One with windows, second with with Ubuntu system. I was happy by setting bios parameters in order to boot from one or another HDD. One day I decided to look at Ubuntu HDD from Windows disc manager. After this procedure Ubuntu does not start anymore. 
I was trying to check Ubuntu file system from install Ubuntu flash drive by using gparted, but this not helped. My boot partition is visible in gparted with boot flag enabled.

How to recover my Ubuntu?

UPD

Error on screan while booted:

```
Selected boot device failed.
Press any key to reboot system.
```

Comment: What version of Windows? Windows updates (which you may not see) may turn UEFI secure boot back on and turn Windows fast start up back on. Are both installs UEFI or both installs BIOS? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Although Ubuntu can read/write to Windows NTFS file systems, Windows knows nothing about how to read/write to Ubuntu ext4 file systems. And if you installed a Windows driver to read/write to ext4 file systems, remove it asap, as it corrupts those partitions.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Since I can't find GRUB menu I go second way. fsck found no errors, but I still can't boot. Is it possible this is boot manager issue?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and a screenshot of gparted when viewing /dev/sdb (your Ubuntu disk).